# BOOTSTRAP modal window to run not start

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

i trying to learn about BOOTSTRAP as suggest here looking this: http://nakupanda.github.io/bootstrap3-dialog/ but i have a small problem. This is complete html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Example of Bootstrap 3 Modals</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<script type="text/javascript">
    BootstrapDialog.show({
            message: 'Hi Apple!',
            message: 'You can not close this dialog by clicking outside and pressing ESC key.',
            closable: true,
            closeByBackdrop: false,
            closeByKeyboard: false,
            buttons: [{
                label: 'Close the dialog',
                action: function(dialogRef){
                    dialogRef.close();
                }
            }]
        });
    });
</script>

<!-- Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
         <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Well, if i have this block:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    BootstrapDialog.show({
            message: 'Hi Apple!',
            message: 'You can not close this dialog by clicking outside and pressing ESC key.',
            closable: true,
            closeByBackdrop: false,
            closeByKeyboard: false,
            buttons: [{
                label: 'Close the dialog',
                action: function(dialogRef){
                    dialogRef.close();
                }
            }]
        });
    });
</script>
```

It not start, but if i use this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#myModal").modal('show');
    });
</script>
```

It start, but not have same result that i want with precedent block.
Then i ask, how i can solve this problem? I should to have modal window that is closable only clicking in related button and not in any part of screen.
Thanks very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because [`bootstrap3-dialog`](https://github.com/nakupanda/bootstrap3-dialog/) is an addon to Bootstrap. You must include additional files for it to work:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://nakupanda.github.io/bootstrap3-dialog/assets/bootstrap-dialog/css/bootstrap-dialog.min.css">
<script src="http://nakupanda.github.io/bootstrap3-dialog/assets/bootstrap-dialog/js/bootstrap-dialog.min.js"></script>
```

Working demo:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<!-- Include CSS and JS files for bootstrap3-dialog -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://nakupanda.github.io/bootstrap3-dialog/assets/bootstrap-dialog/css/bootstrap-dialog.min.css">
<script src="http://nakupanda.github.io/bootstrap3-dialog/assets/bootstrap-dialog/js/bootstrap-dialog.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  
$(document).ready(function(){

  BootstrapDialog.show({
    message: 'Hi Apple!',
    message: 'You can not close this dialog by clicking outside and pressing ESC key.',
    closable: true,
    closeByBackdrop: false,
    closeByKeyboard: false,
    buttons: [{
      label: 'Close the dialog',
      action: function(dialogRef){
        dialogRef.close();
      }
    }]
  });

});
  
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try putting your first block (with all the settings you want) inside a document ready handler like your second block.

Here's the shortcut version:

```
$(function() {
  BootstrapDialog.show({
    message: 'Hi Apple!', 
    message: 'You can not close this dialog by clicking outside and pressing ESC key.',
    closable: true, 
    closeByBackdrop: false,
    closeByKeyboard: false, 
    buttons: [{ 
      label: 'Close the dialog', 
      action: function(dialogRef) { 
        dialogRef.close(); 
      }
    }]
  });
});
```

This should give the Bootstrap library time to load.